# Como mostrar vários marcadores no Google Map API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Não consigo marcar no mapa vários pontos. Poderiam verificar se tem algo de errado com o código?

```
var map;
var idInfoBoxAberto;
var infoBox = [];
var marker ;
var geocoder;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes, longitudes);

    var options = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    for (var i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord[i]),
            map: map,
        });
    }
}

initialize();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendo seu *array* `coord` uma *string*, o trecho que você define a posição de cada marcador está incorreta, já que o construtor da classe [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) deve ao menos existir dois argumentos, que é a **latitude** e **longitude** (nesta ordem), assim como está definido na variável `latlng` no início da função `initialize()`.

Sendo assim, você precisa primeiro separar os valores para definir os valores de latitude e longitude para então jogar na propriedade `position` nas opções da classe [`google.maps.Marker`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker):

```
for (var i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
    var location = coord[i].split(",");

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
        map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: na variavel coord mi retorna os seguintes dados ex:-03.734084,-038.576155

Comment: É uma `string` com este valor?

Comment: isso mesmo! talvez por está nesse formato nao esteja dando certo!!

Comment: Certo, sendo assim eu ajustei minha resposta. Veja se agora vai.

Comment: vc tem ideida de como tracar uma linha entre os pontos?

Comment: Você se refere à rotas de navegação ou linhas retas?

Comment: traçar uma linha reta de um ponto ao outro!

Comment: [Aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?hl=pt-br) tem um exemplo de como realizar isso. Se preferir, pode abrir uma nova pergunta para esta dúvida. Não se esqueça de marcar esta como aceita caso tenha respondido sua pergunta.